# CAS Array Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-server

I have 2 CAS servers on my primary site.I want to use Allow/Block/Quarantine feature of 2010 through which I can allow block Active Sync access for particular devices.Do I need to put the Allow Block list on both the CAS servers or putting it on one will take care for both the CAS servers.

I am using

```
set-CASMailbox -Identity <MailboxIdParameter> -ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs <MultiValuedProperty>
```

to allow or block a particular device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This permission is set on mailbox so does not matters from which cas server we access the mailbox.Once set it will allow or block from all the servers in cas array.